I'm currently working with next.js and react three fiber. Project's going to be very heavy. I am using "Suspense" of react to create Loading
import { Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { Suspense, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// Define a fallback component that will be displayed while loading
const Loading = () => (
  <Flex
    zIndex="1"
    bg="#000000"
    h="100vh"
    w="100vw"
    justifyContent="center"
    alignItems="center"
    position="relative"
  >
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        opacity: 0.8, // Ajusta la opacidad según lo deseado
        filter: 'blur(2px)',
      }}
    >
      <Image
        src="/bg.jpg" // Ruta de la imagen en la carpeta public
        layout="fill" // Establece que la imagen ocupe todo el tamaño del contenedor
        objectFit="cover" // Ajusta el tamaño de la imagen para que cubra completamente el contenedor
      />
    </div>
    {/* Texto de carga */}
    <Flex
      zIndex="2"
      bg="black"
      borderRadius="full"
      padding="2rem"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      width="25vh"
      h="25vh"
      textAlign="center"
      color="white"
      fontFamily="Amatic SC"
      fontSize="2vw"
    >
      Cargando...
    </Flex>
  </Flex>
);

const SuspenseWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadInitialData = async () => {
      try {
        // Simulated delay for data loading
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during initial data loading:', error);
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    loadInitialData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<Flex bg='black'/>}>
      {isLoading ? <Loading /> : children}
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default SuspenseWrapper;

This is my code. I need to get my suspense working correctly. I want to add a loading bar in the future, for what I need to be able to track the charging process of my website.
I'm wrapping my <Home/> section with this function from before (SuspenseWrapper), and I don't know if I am doing that correctly, because as my home section finishes charging, I have a white screen in the middle of the transition between the Loading screen and my home screen. It looks pretty bad to have that white flash. I've tried a lot of things to make it disappear but just couldn't.
I tried using the suspense in its primal way, but the same screen still showed up.
What I need is to fix that white screen and to know how to capture the finishing charging data event. Thanks in advance!
